# QQplot to check normal distributed

Tags: statistics

If I have 10000 data points, how can I check sum(aX+b)/n whether converges to a normal distribution by using qqplot() in R. I am trying to plot the qqplot but not sure how to di it.

For instance, I have mu = 3 and sigma = 5, and my estimated mu, sigma are very closed to 3 and 5. I have 10000 data points in total.

Answer (score 0):

**Three samples.** Let's look at normal probability plots of three samples of size $n = 1000,$ the first of which is sampled from a normal population.

```
set.seed(1124)
x1 = rnorm(1000, 50, 5)
x2 = rgamma(1000, 4, 1/10)
x3 = rbeta(1000, 4, 6)
```

**Histograms and population densities.** Below are histograms of the three samples. Superimposed on each histogram is a red density curve for the relevant population.

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
hist(x1, prob=T, br=15, col="skyblue2", main="n=1000, NORM(50,5)")
 curve(dnorm(x,50,5), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
hist(x2, prob=T, br=15, col="skyblue2", main="n=1000: GAMMA(4,.1)")
 curve(dgamma(x,4,.1), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
hist(x3, prob=T, br=15, col="skyblue2", main="n=1000: BETA(4,6)")
 curve(dbeta(x,4,6), add=T, col="red", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]

**Normal quantile plots.** In R anyhow, it is not necessary to provides values or estimates of population means or variances in order to make such plots.

(In each plot the green reference line
runs through theoretical normal and sample lower and upper quantiles. Normal samples tend to yield points that lie near such reference lines--except possibly for a very few points near the maximum and minimum.)

```
set.seed(1124)
x1 = rnorm(1000, 50, 5)
x2 = rgamma(1000, 4, 1/10)
x3 = rbeta(1000, 4, 6)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
qqnorm(x1, main="n=1000: NORM(50,5)")
 qqline(x1, col="green", lwd=2)
qqnorm(x2, main="n=1000: GAMMA(4,.1)")
 qqline(x2, col="green", lwd=2)
qqnorm(x3, main="n=1000: BETA(4,6)")
 qqline(x3, col="green", lwd=2)
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
```

[image]